# How to rotate a sprite from single pictures with difference rotations?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I want to create a sprite and rotates it at the beginning. The code below is created number `1` in a pictures.

```
sprite = Sprite.Create(texture2, new Rect(0, 252, 84, 84),
         new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f), 100.0f);
```

Now I can snip a pictures to my sprite but I want to create 4 difference sprites which have directions are top, left, right and bottom. How can I do that.

[image]

Note: Using `transform.rotation` doesn't work because this rotates an object that give wrong direction when i control them.

I'm a beginners. Thanks.

Comment: Rotating every individual tank with its transform is the right way to go.

Comment: If you want to rotate them make sure to set the origin point to the middle, or your sprite will rotate around the top left corner and the x and y position may not "look" like they are representing the "correct" location

Answer (score 3):

Try using [transform.Rotate](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html)
It is much easier to encapsulate in methods.
For example:
figure 2:

```
sprite.transform.Rotate(new Vector3(90,0,0));
```

figure 3:

```
sprite.transform.Rotate(new Vector3(180,0,0));
```

figure 4:

```
sprite.transform.Rotate(new Vector3(270,0,0));
```

I hope this answers your question, if not just let me know.

Comment: I would go with this answer too. 
+ to this, to move in the direction the tank is facing I would use this
 
transform.position += transform.forward * Time.deltaTime * movementSpeed;

and this to move back

transform.position += transform.forward * Time.deltaTime * movementSpeed;

Answer (score 0):

Should use Unity "SpriteEditor" for create sprite unity make you a easy way for manage sprite.
unity make an example/tutorial about 2d gamedevelopment and sprite editor
here [Learn Unity 2D](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/2d/sprite-editor)